# laravel Get all models that have array of relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Product model with Tags relation:

```
class Product
{
  public function tags()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('tags')
```

and

```
class Tags
{
  public function products()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('products')
```

how can i retrieve `products` that have all of `tags` with id of `[1,2,3]`

Comment: try: $products->with(['tags' => function($query){
$query->whereIn('id', [1,2,3]);}]);

Comment: @FatemehMajd this will return products that has tags in this array. i mean a product with 1 tag_id also  is in your solution

Comment: In that case, i'm now aware of the eloquent way, but you can query the tables as in: DB::table('blah_blah-1')-join('...')->...;

Comment: Should the products have *one* of these tags or *all* of them?

Comment: Are you wanting products that have all 3 tags?

Comment: yes @RossWilson i'm wanting products that have all 3 tags.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Products Shoulde have all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) with all four parameters:

```
$tagIds = [1, 2, 3];
$products = Product::whereHas('tags', function($query) use($tagIds) {
    $query->whereIn('tags.id', $tagIds);
}, '=', count($tagIds))->get();
```

Comment: Intelligently method!!